# Some problems with vue router reload and components updating

Tags: arrays, vue.js, updates, reload, vue-router

I'm actually working on a VueJs project where I meet some problems.

The 1st is that when I'm reloading page using parameters, I'm throwed back to the root page and I don"t understand why. I'm actually using the vue webpack template and lazy loading for my routes templates.

The 2nd problem is that I'm making a page of comments for my project who's are generated from a array of object. When the user has done posting his comment a new array is loaded from the database and put in the data of the parent as following :

```
parentComponent -> data -> array of objects -> each object = a component
```

So I used this.$set to put datas but it has not worked,I used a foreach loop and now I'm just replacing the array like this :

```
oldArray = new Array
```

But it doesn't work and my child components don't want to update even with forceUpdate().Maybe it's something very silly but I didn't found the answer.
If someone could have the answer that would be very nice to share it.

Here is my parent code:

```
<template>
  <div class='comments'>
    <div v-if="comments.length > 0" class="comments__block">
      <comment-block v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.Id" :comment.sync="comment" :updateHandler="loadComments"></comment-block>
    </div>       
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'Comments',
  data () {
    return {
      page: 1,
      comments: [],
      numberPages: 0,
      resultEmpty: false
    }
  },
  components: {
    'comment-block': commBlock,
  },
  computed: {
  methods: {
    loadComments (nextPage = 1) {
      if (isLogged) {
        axios
        .get(`API query if logged)
        .then(response => {
          if (Success) {
            if (Comments) {
              this.comments = Comments
              this.resultEmpty = false
            } else {
              this.resultEmpty = true
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        })
      } else {
        axios
      .get(`url if not logged`)
      .then(response => {
        if (Success) {
          if (Comments) {
            this.comments = []
            Comments.forEach(c => {
              this.comments.push(c)
            })
            this.resultEmpty = false
          } else {
            this.resultEmpty = true
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loadComments()
  },
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      this.loadComments()
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

And for the children

```
<template>
  <div class='comment-block'>
    <div class="comment-block__header">
      <div class="comment-block__username">
        {{userName}}
      </div>
      <div v-if="isLogged" class="comment-block__likes">
        <input v-model="like" class="comment-block__radio" type="radio" name="likes" id="like" value="Y"/><label class="comment-block__radio-label comment-block__radio-label--like" for="like" v-bind:class="{'comment-block__radio-label--liked': like == 'Y'}" @click="toggle('Y')">{{nbLikes}}<v-icon large color="white">keyboard_arrow_up</v-icon></label>
        <input v-model="like" class="comment-block__radio" type="radio" name="likes" id="dislike" value="N"/><label class="comment-block__radio-label comment-block__radio-label--dislike" for="dislike" v-bind:class="{'comment-block__radio-label--liked': like == 'N'}" @click="toggle('N')">{{nbDislikes}}<v-icon large color="white">keyboard_arrow_down</v-icon></label>
        <input v-model="like" class="comment-block__radio" type="radio" name="likes" id="disapproved" value="D"/><label class="comment-block__radio-label comment-block__radio-label--disapproved" for="disapproved" v-bind:class="{'comment-block__radio-label--liked': like == 'D'}" @click="toggle('D')">{{nbDisapproved}}<v-icon large color="white">report</v-icon></label>
      </div>
      <div v-else class="comment-block__likes">
        <button class="comment-block__button" @click="displayMessage = ! displayMessage" id="like"><p class="comment-block__radio-p comment-block__radio-p--like" for="like">{{comment.NbLikes}}<v-icon large color="white">keyboard_arrow_up</v-icon></p></button>
        <button class="comment-block__button" @click="displayMessage = ! displayMessage" id="dislike"><p class="comment-block__radio-p comment-block__radio-p--dislike" for="dislike">{{comment.NbDislikes}}<v-icon large color="white">keyboard_arrow_down</v-icon></p></button>
        <button class="comment-block__button" @click="displayMessage = ! displayMessage" id="disapproved"><p class="comment-block__radio-p comment-block__radio-p--disapproved" for="disapproved">{{comment.NbDisapproved}}<v-icon large color="white">report</v-icon></p></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-block__body">
      <div cols="12">
        <div class="comment-block__commentary">
          {{commentary }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>              
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'Comments',
  data () {
    return {
      id: this.comment.idComment,
      userName: this.comment.UserName,
      commentary: this.comment.Commentary,
      nbLikes: this.comment.NbLikes,
      nbDislikes: this.comment.NbDislikes,
      nbDisapproved: this.comment.NbDisapproved,
      displayedLikes: this.nbLikes,
      displayedDislikes: this.nbDislikes,
      displayedDisapproved: this.nbDisapproved,
      lastLike: this.comment.LastLike,
      like: this.comment.LastLike,
      displayMessage: false
    }
  },
  props: {
    comment: {type: Object, required: true},
    updateHandler: {type: Function, required: true}
  },
  computed: {
    isLogged () {
      if (this.$store.state.jwt.token) {
        return true
      }
      return false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitLike () {
      var payload = {
        IdComment: this.id,
        Like: this.like
      }
      var header = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: this.$store.state.jwt.token
        }
      }
      axios
      .post('someUrl', payload, header)
      .then(resp => {
        if (Success) {
          this.updateHandler()
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
    },
    toggle (value) {
      if (value === this.like) {
        this.like = ''
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    like (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        this.submitLike()
        switch (oldVal) {
          case 'Y' : this.nbLikes--
            break
          case 'N' : this.nbDislikes--
            break
          case 'D' : this.nbDisapproved--
            break
        }
        switch (newVal) {
          case 'Y' : this.nbLikes++
            break
          case 'N' : this.nbDislikes++
            break
          case 'D' : this.nbDisapproved++
            break
        }
      }
      if (oldVal === newVal) {
        this.like = ''
      }
    },
    comment (newVal) {
      this.$forceUpdate()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

PS: Sorry for my bad english if it is.

Comment: Hello Nathan, and welcome to SO. While you're extremely descriptive in your post, without the offending code, we will be just taking shots in the dark, so please post your code here.

Comment: Can you paste your code? It will be easier for us to try to help you out.

Comment: OK I'm gonna do that thank you

Comment: Here is my code thank you for the help